# How can I get a workflow moving a document into a document set?

Tags: workflow, document, document-set, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that creates a document set based on metadata I enter on documents that I upload. Does anyone know how I can move the same documents with a workflow into the document set?

Answer (score 1):

A Document set is just a folder, so when specifying the destination of a document just add the name of the document set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I know that a document set is just a folder, but I do not find the command in Sharepoint Designer that is able to do what you suggest. Do you know what I can use?

Comment: I don't think there actually is a native action that provides enough control over this. You may want to look at a 'real' workflow system such as Nintex Workflow or a utility tool such as our Workflow Power Pack (Example at http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/automatically-create-mirrored.html)